# Does more miners mean lower gas prices?

Tags: blockchain, consensus, governance

I hope the question is self explanatory but, basically I wonder if the Ethereum code is made in a way that id there is more miners, would that in turn allow for lower gas prices or transactions to be processed faster, in turn requiring less gas to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately(?) that's not how the system works. The system doesn't scale up by adding more processors (miners). No matter how many miners there are, the blocks remain the same size and with very similar interval.

Currently the only ways to make transactions cheaper & faster are:

- Increase block gas limit (fits more transactions in a single block). This has been done a few times during the past year; the size is somewhere around 12M gas currently: https://etherscan.io/chart/gaslimit . But the bigger this is, the more powerful computers the miners need to be so the more centralized the network becomes.
- Wait for Eth 2.0: it's a PoS blockchain so things will most likely be cheaper - unsure about speed. But will have to wait a few years still.
- Use second layer solutions: do most of the transactions in a second layer and only use the main Ethereum blockchain as a security anchor. For example Plasma and Rollups.